# How to change the page name as per us in smarty

Tags: html, smarty

Hello every one i need your help... I was trying to fetch diffrent diffrent name on a page as per i change the page. But i cant figure it out how.
Thing which i am trying to do is...

If i am on login page i want to display login text and if i am on register page i want to show register text. and if i am on my account page i need to show a diffrent text. Please guide me friends how can we do it...

I am trying this.

```
{if $name eq 'Fred'}Welcome Sir.{elseif $name eq 'Wilma'}Welcome Ma'am.{else}Welcome, whatever you are.{/if}
```

But i need to change it and i want to fetch the name from the top and change the text and in url i am getting index.php?view=login

If there will be a login i want to show a text hello else if its register than register now or else i need to show no page found.

Please guide me in it.